# Setting the margins of a Devexpress mvc menu item

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, devexpress

I have a Devexpress MVC Menu in razor and I want to set the margins on the menu items so the menu will fit horizontally on the page. There is a setting.ControlStyle for padding but not margins.
Is there any way I can change the margins so it will fit across the page?

```
@Html.DevExpress().Menu(
        settings =>
        {
            settings.Name = "mDataBinding";
            settings.AllowSelectItem = true;
            settings.Width = 1080;
            settings.ControlStyle.Paddings.PaddingLeft = 0;
            settings.ControlStyle.Paddings.PaddingRight = 0;
            settings.ControlStyle.Font.Size = 9;
            settings.ControlStyle.ItemSpacing = 1;
        }).BindToSiteMap("~/Styles/SiteMaps/Main.sitemap", false).GetHtml()
```

Here is what it currently looks like
[image: Current Menu look]

Comment: http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q292246

Comment: Hi @ShahroozJefriㇱ and what part are you referring to exactly?

Comment: There's a sample here in the last comment: http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q418614

Comment: Your code in the question helped solve my issue regarding paddings :) @WillNZ

Answer (score 1):

I recommend `settings.Width = Unit.Percentage(100);`